# Trying to count rows with non-missing date/category observations: why is this code not working?

Tags: r

I've got a data frame with five categorical variables and two date variables.

I'd like to get a count of the observations for which none of the categorical variables is missing AND for which the difference between the dates is less than or equal to six months. So for this data frame, it would be a count of 1 as only one observation (row 1) meets the criteria.

The code I've tried so far works on the minimal working example but doesn't work when I run it on my actual data set. When I take the code apart the bits and pieces work (eg `as.numeric(difftime(white$dnf_DateDeath, white$RecruitmentFinal,  units = "days")) <= 182.52`) but when together as below I get `[1] NA`. I have no idea why.

Is there a way of building an ifelse() tree, so that the expressions might get evaluated step-wise? Any help would be much appreciated.

Starting point:

```
df <-  
data.frame(sports=c(1,NA,1,1),car=c(1,NA,NA,1),hobbies=c(1,NA,1,1), 
home=c(1,NA,NA,1),office=c(1,1,NA,1), start_date=c("01/01/2016",
"01/01/2016","01/01/2016","01/01/2016"),
leave_date=c("01/04/2016","01/03/2016",NA,"01/12/2016"))
```

I've tried using:

```
library(lubridate)
sum(!is.na(df$sports) &!is.na(df$hobbies) & !is.na(df$car) & 
!is.na(df$home) & !is.na(df$office) & 
as.period(interval(df$start_date, df$leave_date)) <= months(6))
```

And I've also tried:

```
sum(!is.na(df$sports) &!is.na(df$hobbies) & !is.na(df$car) & 
!is.na(df$home) & !is.na(df$office) & 
as.numeric(difftime(df$leave_date, df$start_date,  units = "days")) 
<= 182.52)
```

Comment: Your first attempt gives me `1`, not `NA`. Could you recheck?

Comment: Yes, it works on the minimal working example but not on my extended data set and I have no idea why (which is why it's so hard to come of with a mwe that represents the problem - there shouldn't be one for all I can tell).

Comment: The only thing that could be producing the NAs, I think, is that `as.numeric` statement. If you leave it out do you get a correct answer? If so, check that all your `leave_date` and `start_date` variables are being converted ok by `difftime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to work as expected.

```
df2 <- df[complete.cases(df), ]
df2[abs(difftime(df2$start_date, df2$leave_date, unit = "days")) <= 365.25/2, ]
#  sports car hobbies home office start_date leave_date
#1      1   1       1    1      1 01/01/2016 01/04/2016
```

**EDIT.**
If you want to use package `lubridate` for date arithmetics, you could do

```
library(lubridate)

inx <- dmy(df2$start_date) + months(6) > dmy(df2$leave_date)
df2[inx, ]
#  sports car hobbies home office start_date leave_date
#1      1   1       1    1      1 01/01/2016 01/04/2016
```

Comment: When I run it on my extended data set I get "Error in complete.cases(WTdf) : not all arguments have the same length"

Comment: I don't see how that can possibly happen. Is `WTdf` an object of class `data.frame`?

Comment: It's a data frame, but had some unexpected formatting issues in a few values that escaped my cleaning process. Thanks for the complete.cases() though, didn't know it existed.